# Кэширование в Asp Net MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, кэширование

Подскажите пожалуйста что это за ошибка и как ее исправить? При объявлении:

```
 check_spec = Cache["Specialities"+ instid] as List<Specialities>;
```

вылезает ошибка:

> Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства Cache.insert требуется ссылка на объект.

Вот экранный снимок среды разработки:

[image: Ошибка при вставке в кэш]

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте код в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения. Для этого используйте ссылку «[edit]», расположенную под метками вопроса.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky В данном конкретном случае, картинка была лучше кода, так как на ней как раз было видно, к чему относится слово `Cache`. А теперь это стало совершенно непонятно.

Comment: @Igor Тоже так подумал, но раз просят...

Comment: @Igor, вернул изображение на место. Пусть будет и текст, и экранный снимок.

Comment: Картинка и код не соответствуют.

Answer (score 4):

`Cache` в Вашем коде это класс `System.Web.Caching.Cache`.

Используйте статическое свойство `Cache` (это объект указанного выше класса) класса `System.Web.HttpRuntime`:

```
System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(...
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ого, спасибо, все заработало :)